# Include HTML into other HTML with web components

Tags: html, web-component

What is the right way to insert HTML snippet into main HTML file with HTML5 imports?

The answer to more generic question https://stackoverflow.com/a/22142111/239247 mentions that it is possible to do:

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="header.html">
</head>
```

But this doesn't work. I don't need to insert JS and CSS. Only plain HTML markup inserted at the top of `<body>`. What is the most simple way to do this and keep HTML readable?

Comment: Did you look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: That's experimental. You may have to resort to something like http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp

It says:

> HTML Includes in Future HTML. Including a portion of HTML in HTML is, unfortunately, not (yet) supported by HTML.

So this is on its way, but not here yet.

EDIT: If you are able to, I would use PHP, which is close to the level of cleanliness. The link I inclueded shows multiple ways to do what you are trying to do.

Late edit: if it still counts (for those worried about sourcing): http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

Comment: @techtonik It's always been a great resource for me. Just saying. I don't see peoples' problem with it.

Comment: Again, always has been for me. I trust them.

Comment: There is no data when this information was updated, so I have no reason to trust them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have found to do this is to use ASP.NET and .cshtml files and use razor, as seen here: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts
Beyond simply inserting html into other html this also allows you to have consistent navigation bars, footers, etc. and minimizes your code profile. Also, the use of a layout file gives the site a better feel as only a section of the site refreshes when you click an internal link, as opposed to the whole site.

Comment: ASP.NET is not HTML5 web components standard.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this from [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#usingcontent), but it is far from being readable. This is the ideal way:

```
<body>
  <include src="header.html"/>
</body>
```

And this is how it is implemented by HTML5 imports:

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="header.html">
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    document.body.appendChild(
      document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]')
        .import
        .querySelector('body')
        .cloneNode(true));
  </script>
</body>
```

Notes:

- not clear how to choose include if both `header.html` and `footer.html` are there
- `querySelector('body')` is required to avoid `Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'BODY'.`
- not clear how to insert `<body>` tag contents without the tag itself
- HTML5 import doesn't work in Firefox (38) http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports =/